# Problema con las condiciones if

Tags: php, html, mysql

solicito de su apoyo para poder realizar esta parte de mi pequeño sistema, tengo un dilema al momento y de mandar a imprimir en PDF unos valores, tengo un archivo que se llama imprimir_perfil_reumatico.php el cual mando a imprime en pdf los siguientes valores:

Antiestreolisinas, Proteínas C Reactivas, Factor reumatoide, Volumen de segmentación globular y Ácido Úrico le cual es un dilema por que es como un gran numero de comparaciones que tengo que hacer y dependiendo de eso mando imprimir el formato de los valores, por ejemplo si piden los primeros 3 valores lo imprimo bien si pido 4 igual bien e individual bien menos el de Factor reumatoide que es me imprime todos los valores aunque estén vacíos y no me imprime todos los valores cunado están llenos.

Lo que quiero es que me imprima así como lo tengo en el código que si el usuario solo mete un valor solo se imprima ese valor si imprime 2 que solo se imprima 2 valores y así hasta que guarda todos los valores se imprima todos los valores en el pdf, Mi pregunta es, ¿Como le puedo hacer para poder imprimirlo asi?

```
    include("config/db.php");
        include("config/conexion.php");
        include("docs_pdf/cabecera_estudios_pdf.php");
        include("docs_pdf/pie_estudios_pdf.php");
    
       $num_fac=$_GET["num_factura"];
       $id_cliente=$_GET["idcliente"];
       $fecha=$_GET["fecha"];
       $id_medico=$_GET["idmedico"];
       $sexo=$_GET["sexo"];
       $sql="SELECT c.nombre_cliente,q.* from clientes c,resul_factor_reumatoide q where q.numero_factura='".$num_fac."' and q.id_cliente='".$id_cliente."' and c.id_cliente=q.id_cliente and q.fecha='". $fecha."'";
       $resul=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
       $rw_resul=mysqli_fetch_array($resul);
    
    $antiestre = $rw_resul["antiestre"];
         $proteinac = $rw_resul["proteinac"];
         $factorreu = $rw_resul["factorreu"];
         $vsg = $rw_resul["vsg"];
         $au = $rw_resul["au"];
    
    **//El primer if checo si estan llenos procedo con mi if anidado si estan vacios mando un mensaje con else de que no hay valores y tiene que ingresar alguno.**
    if($factorreu || $antiestre || $proteinac || $vsg || $au){
    
    **//Con este if que deberia de checar que todos tengan todos los valores deberia de imprimirme normal todos los valores pero no lo hace no me imprime cuando tengo datos en todos los valores.**
    if(isset($factorreu) and isset($antiestre) and isset($proteinac) and isset($vsg) and isset($au) || empty($factorreu) and empty($antiestre) and empty($proteinac) and empty($vsg) and empty($au)){
    }
    
    **//Factor Reumatoide solo (Este no me funciona ya que me manda imprimir los demas campos aunque solo mande  a imprimir Factor reumatoide)** 
    if(isset($factorreu) and empty($antiestre) and empty($proteinac) and empty($vsg) and empty($au) || empty($factorreu)){
    }
    
    **//ANTIESTREPTOLISINAS solo (Si me funciona ya que solo imprime el que quiero)**
    if(empty($factorreu) and isset($antiestre) and empty($proteinac) and empty($vsg) and empty($au)){
    }
    
    **//PCR solo (Si me funciona ya que solo imprime el que quiero)**
    if(empty($factorreu) and empty($antiestre) and isset($proteinac) and empty($vsg) and empty($au)){
    }
    
    **//VSG solo (Si me funciona ya que solo imprime el que quiero)**
    if(empty($factorreu) and empty($antiestre) and empty($proteinac) and isset($vsg) and empty($au)){
    }
    
    **//PCR, antiestres, factor reumatoide solo esos 3 (Si me funciona ya que solo imprime el que quiero)**
    if(isset($factorreu) and isset($antiestre) and isset($proteinac) and empty($vsg) and empty($au)){
    }
    
    **//PCR, antiestres, factor reumatoide, VSG solo esos 4 (Si me funciona ya que solo imprime el que quiero)**
    if(isset($factorreu) and isset($antiestre) and isset($proteinac) and isset($vsg) and empty($au)){
    }
    
    **//PCR, antiestres, factor reumatoide, AU solo esos 4 (Si me funciona ya que solo imprime el que quiero)**
    if(isset($factorreu) and isset($antiestre) and isset($proteinac) and empty($vsg) and isset($au)){
    }
    }else{  **//(Si me funciona ya que imprime el mensaje de que los valores estan vacios)**
        echo $cadena=' No hay información del paciente que imprimir.

 Favor de llenar algun campo para poder imprimir correctamente.
```

';

```
 }
```

En el código me imprime bien los valores solos menos el factor reumatoide que me manda imprimir los demás campos vacíos y no se porque y cuando están todos los campos llenos en mi BD no los imprime, espero me puedan ayudar a resolver esto ya que ya lo he intentado y leído pero no logro resolverlo a la perfección de igual si hay alguna otra manera de hacer el código un poco mas ligero para no repetir todo ese código lo super agradecería mucho.

Comment: Como estas recibiendo los datos en tu base de datos? a través de un formulario? puedes agregar esa información de código a tu pregunta, parece que lo que necesitas hacer es un filtro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
    Para no tener que checar a cada rato el isset(); te recomiendo esto
    $proteinac = isset($rw_resul["proteinac"]) ? $rw_resul["proteinac"] : '';
    $factorreu = isset($rw_resul["factorreu"]) ? $rw_resul["factorreu"] : '';
    $vsg = isset($rw_resul["factorreu"]) ? $rw_resul["vsg"] : '';
    $au = isset($rw_resul["factorreu"]) ? $rw_resul["au"] : '';
    
    **//El primer if checo si estan llenos procedo con mi if anidado si estan vacios mando un mensaje con else de que no hay valores y tiene que ingresar alguno.**
    if($factorreu || $antiestre || $proteinac || $vsg || $au){
    
    **//Con este if que deberia de checar que todos tengan todos los valores deberia de imprimirme normal todos los valores pero no lo hace no me imprime cuando tengo datos en todos los valores.**
    if(isset($factorreu) and isset($antiestre) and isset($proteinac) and isset($vsg) and isset($au) || empty($factorreu) and empty($antiestre) and empty($proteinac) and empty($vsg) and empty($au)){
    }

    Esta parte de arriba creo que no te está funcionando por el operador || ya que la condición dice que cuando estén todos o no esté ninguno.
    Prueba con lo siguiente
    if($factorreu && $antiestre && $proteinac && $vsg && $au}
    
    **//Factor Reumatoide solo (Este no me funciona ya que me manda imprimir los demas campos aunque solo mande  a imprimir Factor reumatoide)** 
    if(isset($factorreu) and empty($antiestre) and empty($proteinac) and empty($vsg) and empty($au) || empty($factorreu)){
    }

    Con esta parte de arriba prueba con esto
    if($factorreu && !$antiestre && !$proteinac && !$vsg && !$au){
    }
```

Lo de los `isset` es una recomendación, puedes dejar todo como estaba y modificar solos los `if` que te menciono quitando el operador 'or' `||`.
Creo que eso es lo que te está afectando.

Comment: Hola, veo mucho mas ordenado el código usando ternario, lo que no entiendo es como esto soluciona el error que tiene a la hora de mandar a imprimir los datos. Me ayudas a entender por favor ?

Comment: el ternario solo lo uso para no tener que escribir en cada sentencia if el isset o el empty y sustituyendo el empti con una negación (!), esto ayuda a que sea mas legible y se vea un poco más limpio. Ahora, el problema creo que lo tiene en el operador or que utiliza en esos if específicos. ya que el primer if dice que estén todas o no esté ninguna y la intención del primero es solo cuando estén todas las variables seteadas. Lo mismo en el siguiente if, se desea que solo cuando esté factorreu y las demas no, pero tiene un operador or que dice cuando no esté factorreu.